# Whether we should use classes in Typescript for Node or the same way as we are doing in javascript exporting functions development

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a concern regarding Node development in Typescript.
 I have been working with a node developer who is proficient in node with javascript but now we have decided to move from javascript to typescript, which is a good decision.

The problem is as we have started writing code in typescript but as we are facing conflicts to choose should we use modular way in typescript or use class.

Option 1:

```
ab.ts
export function a () {
will write whole code here for that
}
```

Option 2:

```
ab.ts

export class Ab {

constructor(){
}

public a() {
//write code here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use TypeScript and don't use Class / Interface then you are not getting the most out of it. So, I would highly recommend to structure your project in such way that you can make use of class/interface.